# Проверка соответсвия домена сертификату

Tags: python, scrapy, certificate

Проблема: scrapy не может определить, что у сайта проблемы с сертификатом. Как мне узнать, что сертификат не подходит для домена?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-clientcontextfactory

Comment: убрал ссылку, чтобы вопрос не выглядел как спам. надеюсь, без конкретной ссылки суть вопроса не меняется ни на йоту.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ответь вопросом. Спасибо за ответ, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-clientcontextfactory

По умолчанию scrapy не проверят валидность сертификата. Если нужно проверять сертификат, то можно использовать `scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.BrowserLikeContextFactory`.